# Riverpod future provider not rebuilding ui

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

My problem is that when I run the app, the data doesn't show up on the UI. The code below is rendered under a bottom navigation bar format which is a stateful widget. To my knowledge the below code should work (show data on the initial running of app).

The code works but the data is only shown when I press hot reload. I've tried everything that I know but it still doesn't show data when I start the app.

```
final imageControllerProvider = Provider((ref) {
  return ImageController();
});

final mainScreenImages = FutureProvider<List<String>>((ref) async {
  List<String> list = [];
  list = await ref.watch(imageControllerProvider).getImages();
  return list;
});

class ImageController{

Future<List<String>> getImages() async {
    List<String> imageUrls = [];

    try {
      final Reference reference =   _storage.ref().child("weed/");
      reference.listAll().then((value) {
        for (var element in value.items) {
          element.getDownloadURL().then((e) => imageUrls.add(e));
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    return imageUrls;
  }
}
```

```
class GenerateImages extends ConsumerWidget {
  const GenerateImages({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final imageList = ref.watch(mainScreenImages);
    final double screenwidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double screenheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return imageList.when(data: (data) {
      return Text('$data');
      
    }, error: (_, __) {
      return const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text("OOPS"),
        ),
      );
    }, loading: () {
      return const Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator());
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because in `getImages()` you are not awaiting the results instead you are using the `then()` handler to register callbacks. Replace your `getImages()` function with this and try.

```dart
Future<List<String>> getImages() async {
    List<String> imageUrls = [];

    try {
      final Reference reference = _storage.ref().child("weed/");
      final value = await reference.listAll();
      for (var element in value.items) {
          final url = await element.getDownloadURL();
          imageUrls.add(url);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    return imageUrls;
  }
}
```